# FIFO Memory Volatile or Non Volatile

Tags: memory, interface, fifo

I am referring to IDT7203 datasheet. (  MEMORY FIFO 2048X9 25NS )

Link here: http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/idt-integrated-device-technology-inc/7203L25J/800-2478-5-ND/2014356

My question is this FIFO memory is Volatile or Non Volatile type?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Volatile. is there specific doubt or case due to which you are looking for a FIFO with non volatile options?

Comment: Do you mean IDT7203 is volatile .. It is not mentioned in datasheet, hence confused.

Comment: pls see the picture in the answer below

Answer (score 1):

While the datasheet may not state that these FIFOs are volatile, their normal use would require a volatile memory, as they will normally be written to frequently, at full processor speeds, like normal RAM.

Non-volatile solid state memory (EEPROM, FLASH) can usually only tolerate a limited number of write cycles, and usually requires special slow operations for writes, so would not be suitable for use in a FIFO.

Answer (score 1):

To answer only the volatile feature of IDT part:
The RAM nomenclature used should help you convince yourself that the part is volatile.

Non volatile write speed are way less than high speed volatile memories. Pls see answer from @peter.

Also, below:

> Data is stored in the **RAM** array sequentially and independently of any
>   on-going read operation

Both from page 1 of the datasheet.

[image]